# How can I use apue.h on mac 10.9.4

Tags: compiling

I tried to compile source code from Advanced Programming in the UNIX® Environment on my mac, but after `make`, the compiling just quit  with this error:

```
... 
clang: error: unknown argument: '-R.' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
make[1]: *** [t4] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Comment: The book is buggy - see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067541/working-code-for-advanced-programming-in-the-unix-environment-2ed-preferably-on) answer on Stack Exchange

Comment: @garethTheRed: Your link is about the *2nd edition* that was released more than 8 years ago. There is now a third edition from last year (OS X 10.6.8 is one of the systems on which it was tested). Not sure if your link and your assessment still apply.

Answer (score 0):

It's a gcc compiler pain that "clang: error: unknown argument: '-R.'" 
So I fixed the problem by changing "-R." to "-R" in /apue.3e/db/Makefile:

like this:

ifeq "$(PLATFORM)" "macos"
  EXTRALD=-R